# My GetComponent<>() function in my game engine's Entity-Component-System returns Compiler Error C2440

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, components, game-engine, entity-component-system

This question is regarding a compiler error from Visual Studio 2019 in a C++ application operating within a Windows 10 OS. It is probably an intermediate-level or higher question.

### Summary

I have this function:

```cpp
template<typename T> T* Scene::GetComponent(EntityID entityID) {
    CompTypeID typeID = TypeToID<T>();
    if (HasComponent<T>(entityID)) {
        CompIndex index = componentIndexes[typeID][entityID];
        return components[typeID][index];
    }
    else return nullptr;
}
```

This function results in compiler error C2440:

> 'return': cannot convert from '_Ty' to 'T*' with [_Ty=Component*] and [T=Name]

This error also has these two messages attached to it:

> message : Cast from base to derived requires dynamic_cast or static_cast
>
> message : see reference to function template instantiation 'T *Scene::GetComponent(EntityID)' being compiled with [T=Name]

This error appears 3 times, each with T equaling Name, Transform, & Sprite (each of the components so far in my game engine)

Compiler Error C2440 on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2440?view=vs-2019

### Function Explanation

#### ECS Design

My Entity Component System stores entities and components via two arrays of arrays.

The first is `componentIndexes`, which is used to index by entity into the second array, `components` which will return based upon index, a component.  Essentially, if you've heard of condensing arrays using a "sparse" array and a 'dense' array, `componentIndexes` is my sparse array and `components` is my dense array to store components in my scene.

*In short:*

`componentIndexes` stores an index to components of type CompIndex, provided: [ComponentType][entityID] **| See Graphic 1A**

`components` stores component data of type Component*, provided: [ComponentType][index] **| See Graphic 1B**

```cpp
// An array of arrays of indexes into the component arrays, acquired via Entities and Component Types
// Y - std::array of sets with each element position being representative of a Component Type ID
// & each element value being X
// X - std::vector of indexes with each element position being representative of an Entity ID
// & each element value being representative of the position of the component in the component containter(components)
/****EXAMPLE:****
  _E0_E1_E2_E3_   E = Entity ID | C = Component ID | i = Index
C0|i0|i1|~~|i2|     **A ~~ IS REPRESENTATIVE OF A NULL/NAN VALUE (of actual value equal to -1)**
  |--+--+--+--+-    Entity 0 has only Component 0 at index 0
C1|~~|~~|i0|i1|     Entity 1 has Components 0(indx1) and 2(indx0)
  |--+--+--+--+-    Entity 2 has only Component 1(indx0)
C2|~~|i0|~~|i1|     Entity 3 has Components 0(indx2), 1(indx1), and 2(indx1)
****************/
std::array<std::vector<CompIndex>, TOTAL_COMPONENT_TYPES> componentIndexes;
```

**`Graphic 1A | componentIndexes`**

```cpp
// An array of vectors of Component*s, holding each components' data
// Y - std::array of vectors with each element position being representative of a Component Type
// & each element value being X
// X - std::vector of Component*s with each element position being indexed into via Entity IDs
// & each element value holding the data concerning a certain component
/****EXAMPLE:****
  _i0_i1_i2_i3_   CD = Component Data | C = Component ID | i = Index
C0|CD|CD|CD|~~|     Component 0 has 3 components
  |--+--+--+--+-
C1|CD|CD|~~|~~|     Component 1 has 2 components
  |--+--+--+--+-
C2|CD|CD|~~|~~|     Component 2 has 2 components
****************/
std::array<std::vector<Component*>, TOTAL_COMPONENT_TYPES> components;
```

**`Graphic 1B | components`**

#### Line-by-Line

```cpp
CompTypeID typeID = TypeToID<T>();
```

This function works as expected, and returns an enum CompTypeID that serves as a numerical representation of component types.  This can be used to index into my `componentIndexes` and `components` arrays, based upon the component type I'm targeting.

```cpp
if (HasComponent<T>(entityID)) {
    . . .
}
else return nullptr;
```

This function works as expected, and returns a bool whether or not an entity has a specific component.  It will return false if the provided type T is not a component or if the entity does not have that component.
Else return nullptr is the self-explanatory fail-state of this function.

```cpp
CompIndex index = componentIndexes[typeID][entityID];
return components[typeID][index];
```

These functions get and return the component, of type `Component*`.  How this does this is explained in **ECS Design**. each element in `components` should be stored components - these are structs and are inherited from an empty struct `Component` (ex. `struct Name : Component {};`).  Because they're inherited from the parent class Component, I should be able to store each child "component" in `components` because it stores types of `Component*`.

### What I Think The Problem Is

The type T of `GetComponent<T>(EntityID)` is going to be equal to Name, Transform, or Sprite.  The storage type of `components` is a `Component*`.  While Name*s, `Transform*`s, & `Sprite*`s can all be stored in `Component*`, it appears that the compiler won't let me assign data of type `Component*` to data of type `Name*` (or other components) - so while theoretically I should be able to fetch the Name data from my array of `Component*`s, I have no way to do so due to that I can't send it away from the GetComponent function as a `Name*`.

I fear that this issue may be caused by a fundamental misunderstanding of how storing children in an array of parents works - maybe this only stores the parent part of the child?

I only can imagine this being fixed one of two ways.

1. There may be a way for me to get the child's information, given the parent's pointer's location - maybe by offsetting the pointer in memory based upon the size of the parent and child pointer if they're contiguous with one another?  I don't think C++ exposes memory references in that capacity, maybe that kind-of approach would only be possible using Assembly due to pointer information being hidden behind typenames (like `int*` or `Component*`).
2. The other way could be some magic using smart pointers or (as the message attached to the error said) explicit dynamic_cast-ing or static_cast-ing; but I have no clue how any of these 3 things work, what they do, how to use them, or when they should be used.

Those are my best guesses - they're really shots in the dark from me.  If you have a better idea, please share it and I'll do my best to look into it.  This is a compiler error that I found little documentation or talk about in my Google searches, so I figured it would be appropriate to contribute with this.

### Disclaimer

Sometimes I find that I've missed some basic information that most people pick up early due to structured class curriculum. I'm guessing that this is where I will be learning about smart pointers and dynamic pointers.

### Resources

**Scene.h**

```cpp
#ifndef SCENE_H
#define SCENE_H
#pragma once

#include "Components.h"
#include "Systems.h"
#include "Entity.h"
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <queue>

class Scene {
private:
    // An array of arrays of indexes into the component arrays, acquired via Entities and Component Types
    // Y - std::array of sets with each element position being representative of a Component Type ID
    // & each element value being X
    // X - std::vector of indexes with each element position being representative of an Entity ID
    // & each element value being representative of the position of the component in the component container(components)
    /****EXAMPLE:****
      _E0_E1_E2_E3_   E = Entity ID | C = Component ID | i = Index
    C0|i0|i1|~~|i2|     **A ~~ IS REPRESENTATIVE OF A NULL/NAN VALUE (of actual value equal to -1)**
      |--+--+--+--+-    Entity 0 has only Component 0 at index 0
    C1|~~|~~|i0|i1|     Entity 1 has Components 0(indx1) and 2(indx0)
      |--+--+--+--+-    Entity 2 has only Component 1(indx0)
    C2|~~|i0|~~|i1|     Entity 3 has Components 0(indx2), 1(indx1), and 2(indx1)
    ****************/
    std::array<std::vector<CompIndex>, TOTAL_COMPONENT_TYPES> componentIndexes;

    // An array of vectors of Component*s, holding each components' data, acquired via Index & Component Type
    // Y - std::array of vectors with each element position being representative of a Component Type
    // & each element value being X
    // X - std::vector of Component*s with each element position being indexed into via Entity IDs
    // & each element value holding the data concerning a certain component
    /****EXAMPLE:****
      _i0_i1_i2_i3_   CD = Component Data | C = Component ID | i = Index
    C0|CD|CD|CD|~~|     Component 0 has 3 components
      |--+--+--+--+-
    C1|CD|CD|~~|~~|     Component 1 has 2 components
      |--+--+--+--+-
    C2|CD|CD|~~|~~|     Component 2 has 2 components
    ****************/
    std::array<std::vector<Component*>, TOTAL_COMPONENT_TYPES> components;

    std::queue<EntityID> oldEntityIDs;
    std::array<std::queue<CompIndex>, TOTAL_COMPONENT_TYPES> oldCompIndexes;
    EntityID GenerateNewEntityID();
    CompIndex GenerateNewCompIndex(CompTypeID compType);
public:
    Scene();

    void Update();

    EntityID NewEntity();
    EntityID GetEntityID(std::string entityName);
    Signature GetEntityComponentSignature(EntityID entityID);
    std::vector<EntityID> GetEntitiesWithComponents(Signature components);
    void DeleteEntity(EntityID entityID);

    // template<typename T> T* AddComponent(EntityID entityID); // Same issue as GetComponent
    template<typename T> T* GetComponent(EntityID entityID);
    template<typename T> bool HasComponent(EntityID entityID);
    bool HasComponents(Signature signComponents, EntityID entityID);
    template<typename T> void DeleteComponent(EntityID entityID);
    void DeleteComponents(Signature signComponents, EntityID entityID);
};

#endif // SCENE_H
```

**Scene.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Scene.h"

Scene::Scene() {

}

void Scene::Update() {
    // RENDER SYSTEM
    for (EntityID entityID : GetEntitiesWithComponents(RenderSystem::required)) {
        RenderSystem::Update(GetComponent<Transform>(entityID), GetComponent<Sprite>(entityID));
    }
}

EntityID Scene::GenerateNewEntityID() {
    EntityID newID;
    if (oldEntityIDs.empty()) {
        newID = (EntityID)componentIndexes[0].size();
    }
    else {
        newID = oldEntityIDs.front();
        oldEntityIDs.pop();
    }
    return newID;
}

CompIndex Scene::GenerateNewCompIndex(CompTypeID typeID) {
    CompIndex newIndex;
    if (oldCompIndexes[typeID].empty()) {
        newIndex = components[typeID].size();
    }
    else {
        newIndex = oldCompIndexes[typeID].front();
        oldCompIndexes[typeID].pop();
    }
    return newIndex;
}

EntityID Scene::NewEntity() {
    // generate entity ID
    EntityID entityID = GenerateNewEntityID();
    // populate entity index
    for (std::vector<CompIndex> componentSparse : componentIndexes) {
        componentSparse[entityID] = NO_COMPONENT;
    }
    // add default entity components
    //AddComponent<Name>(entityID);
    //AddComponent<Transform>(entityID);
    return entityID;
}

EntityID Scene::GetEntityID(std::string entityName) {
    for (EntityID entityID : GetEntitiesWithComponents(IDName)) {
        if (GetComponent<Name>(entityID)->name == entityName) {
            return entityID;
        }
    }
    return 0; // TODO: resolve "NO_ENTITY" case
}

Signature Scene::GetEntityComponentSignature(EntityID entityID) {
    Signature signature;
    // for each component type
    for (CompTypeID i = (CompTypeID)0; i < TOTAL_COMPONENT_TYPES; i = (CompTypeID)(i + (CompTypeID)1)) {
        // if component type is on entity
        if (componentIndexes[i][entityID] != NO_COMPONENT) {
            // mark that bit of the signature to true
            signature.set(i);
        }
    }
    return signature;
}

std::vector<EntityID> Scene::GetEntitiesWithComponents(Signature components) {
    std::vector<EntityID> entities;
    // TODO: write GetEntittiesWithComponents
    return entities;
}

void Scene::DeleteEntity(EntityID entityID) {
    // delete entity Components
    DeleteComponents(GetEntityComponentSignature(entityID), entityID);
    // delete entity indexes
    for (std::vector<CompIndex> componentSparse : componentIndexes) {
        componentSparse.erase(componentSparse.begin() + entityID);
    }
    // add ID to list of avaliable IDs
    oldEntityIDs.push(entityID);
    return;
}

// Same issue as GetComponent()
/*template<typename T> T* Scene::AddComponent(EntityID entityID) {
    CompTypeID typeID = TypeToID<T>();
    if (typeID == IDNotAComponent || componentsSparse[typeID][entityID] != NO_COMPONENT) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else {
        CompIndex index = GenerateNewCompIndex(typeID);
        componentsSparse[typeID][entityID] = index;
        components[typeID][index] = new T; // TODO Ensure, does this work?? (T if not pointer could have issue?)
        return &components[typeID][index];
    }
}*/

template<typename T> T* Scene::GetComponent(EntityID entityID) {
    CompTypeID typeID = TypeToID<T>();
    if (HasComponent<T>(entityID)) {
        CompIndex index = componentIndexes[typeID][entityID];
        return components[typeID][index];
    }
    else return nullptr;
}

template<typename T> bool Scene::HasComponent(EntityID entityID) {
    CompTypeID typeID = TypeToID<T>();
    if (typeID == IDNotAComponent) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (componentIndexes[typeID][entityID] == NO_COMPONENT) {
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

bool Scene::HasComponents(Signature signComponents, EntityID entityID) {
    // for each component type
    for (CompTypeID i = (CompTypeID)0; i < TOTAL_COMPONENT_TYPES; i = (CompTypeID)(i + (CompTypeID)1)) {
        // if component type is in component signature
        if (signComponents.test(i)) {
            // if component type is not on entity
            if (componentIndexes[i][entityID] == NO_COMPONENT) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

template<typename T> void Scene::DeleteComponent(EntityID entityID) {
    CompTypeID typeID = TypeToID(T);
    if (typeID == nullptr || componentIndexes[typeID][entityID] != NO_COMPONENT) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        CompIndex index = componentIndexes[typeID][entityID];
        // delete component
        delete components[typeID][index];
        components[typeID][index] = nullptr;
        // delete component index
        componentIndexes[typeID][entityID] = NO_COMPONENT;
        oldCompIndexes[typeID].push(index);
        return;
    }
}

void Scene::DeleteComponents(Signature signComponents, EntityID entityID) {
    // for each component type
    for (CompTypeID i = (CompTypeID)0; i < TOTAL_COMPONENT_TYPES; i = (CompTypeID)(i + (CompTypeID)1)) {
        // if component type is in component signature
        if (signComponents.test(i)) {
            // if component type is on entity
            if (componentIndexes[i][entityID] != NO_COMPONENT) {
                CompIndex index = componentIndexes[i][entityID];
                // delete component
                delete components[i][index];
                components[i][index] = nullptr;
                // delete component index
                componentIndexes[i][entityID] = NO_COMPONENT;
                oldCompIndexes[i].push(index);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

**Entity.h**

```cpp
#ifndef ENTITY_H
#define ENTITY_H
#pragma once

#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>

typedef std::uint16_t EntityID;

// Maximum number of entities allowed in a scene
const EntityID MAX_ENTITIES = std::numeric_limits<EntityID>::max(); // 65535

#endif // ENTITY_H
```

**Components.h**

```cpp
#ifndef COMPONENTS_H
#define COMPONENTS_H
#pragma once

#include <bitset>

#include "Name.h"
#include "Transform.h"
#include "Sprite.h"

enum CompTypeID {
    IDName,
    IDTransform,
    IDSprite,
    TOTAL_COMPONENT_TYPES,
    IDNotAComponent
};

template<typename T> CompTypeID TypeToID() {
    if (std::is_same<T, Name>()) {
        return IDName;
    }
    else if (std::is_same<T, Transform>()) {
        return IDTransform;
    }
    else if (std::is_same<T, Sprite>()) {
        return IDSprite;
    }
    else return IDNotAComponent;
}

// Component Signature
typedef std::bitset<TOTAL_COMPONENT_TYPES> Signature;

// Component Index
typedef int CompIndex;

const CompIndex NO_COMPONENT = -1;

#endif // COMPONENTS_H
```

**Name.h**

```cpp
#ifndef NAME_H
#define NAME_H
#pragma once

#include "Component.h"
#include <string>

struct Name : Component {
public:
    std::string name;
};

#endif // NAME_H
```

**Component.h**

```cpp
#ifndef COMPONENT_H
#define COMPONENT_H
#pragma once

struct Component {
};

#endif // COMPONENT_H
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm possibly missing something as your post is rather long and I didn't read all of it, but can't you do what the error message says and replace

```
return components[typeID][index];
```

with

```
return static_cast<T*>(components[typeID][index]);
```

As far as I could tell this is just the common case of having a pointer to a base class which you know is actually pointing to a derived class. `static_cast` is the solution to that problem.

Impressive coding for someone who is self taught BTW.

Comment: It does look like a dynamic_cast would be better fit to that, as it would return a nullptr in case the conversion is not valid.

Comment: @Gusgo99 As far as I could tell the classes concerned do not have any virtual functions so `dynamic_cast` would not work. Also the preceding code `HasComponent<T>` seems to be a check that the type is correct for the cast being attempted. But I agree, in some circumstances `dynamic_cast` would be the correct option, but I think not in the code above.